# NSData vs. Archiving

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I guess I just don't know what the difference is because I don't understand the "black box" but what is the difference between using either one of these methods?

When should I be using

```
NSData
writeToFile: atomically:
```

and when should I be using

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: toFile:]
```

And what are the pros and cons to using each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two APIs do different things:

- `NSData` writes out "raw" bytes to the file. You can restore the structure behind these bytes by assuming that the bytes that you read back are in the right places. In a sense, this is similar to applying a cookie cutter to a piece that has some structure, expecting the right pieces to appear in the right spots. A direct consequence of this approach is that the data does not survive changes of code - if the structure into which you read your data did change, saved data from before the change will cause errors.
- `NSKeyedArchiver` preserves the structure of the object along with its data. This results in a slightly larger archives, yet the structure becomes more robust, in terms of surviving changes to the underlying data.

If you need to save a simple piece of unstructured data, you could use either one. If the data that you are saving has structure, prefer `NSKeyedArchiver`, especially if you would like to preserve some flexibility in the future.